# Internet Explorer destroys context on a:commandButton

Tags: java, internet-explorer, jsf, get, seam

I am experiencing some issues when using an a:commandButtonin  Internet Explorer. I am using an `<a:commandButton>` with an action to add a details object. This is working just fine when I use Chrome or Firefox. However, when clicking the add button in Internet Explorer, the context is destroyed and a new one is created.

Some code:
**ListPage.xhtml**

```
<a:commandButton action="#{articleDetail.add}"
                            value="Add" id="PopadArticleBtn"
                            reRender="#{facesContext.maximumSeverity eq null ? 'ArticlePanel' : 'PopArticle, errorMsg'}"
                            oncomplete="#{facesContext.maximumSeverity eq null ? 'Richfaces.hideModalPanel(\'addArticle\');' : ''}">
```

And finally the **ArticleDetail.java** class: (Getters & setters included)

```
@Name("articleDetail")
@Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
@AutoCreate
public class ArticleDetail extends EntityQuery<ArticleDetail> {
    private String fuuPm;
    private String fuuTm;
    private String fuuDc;
    private String fuuDn;
    private String fuuVc;
    private String fuuEc;
    private String fuuIc;
    private String fuuTc;
    private String fuuUc;

    public void add() {
    Boolean unique = Boolean.TRUE;
    Boolean empty = Boolean.FALSE;
    article = populateArticle(
            article,
            getEntityManager().find(
                    ArticleMaster.class,
                    new ArticleMasterId(Integer.parseInt(fuuPm), Integer
                            .parseInt(fuuTm), fuuDc, fuuDn, fuuVc, fuuEc,
                            fuuIc, fuuTc, fuuUc)));
}
```

So the **problem:** in chrome, when debugging, all the attributes have a value, in internet explorer all the values are `null` because of the nex context created

I really have no clue why other browsers seem to leave the conversation context intact and IE somehow causes a new context.

**Similar question**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906774/a4jcommandbutton-causes-full-page-reload-on-ie7

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand - so if you click on the link in IE what do you get in your URL bar?

Comment: @dratewka When I click on the link in IE, Chrome or FF, I get the correct url (`http://localhost:8080/oms/ArticleDetail.seam?fuuPm=201306&fuuTm=201306&fuuDc=94111&fuuDn=G713067R0001&fuuVc=FFSO+&fuuEc=+EWP&fuuIc=FR&fuuTc=DO&fuuUc=PCT0011869&logic=and&cid=16&conversationPropagation=join`)

Comment: The problem is, when I try to persist an ArticleDetail, the article attributes are filled in using the parameters, but since they are null in IE, this doesn't work

Comment: ok let me get this straight - 1) the URL is the same on each browser; 2) this is a GET request so all the parameter values are in the URL; 3) on the server side you get null parameter values when clicking in IE. Right?

Comment: My first guess would be that it's something on the server side - do you have any request filters or such? Do you experience the same problem with other get requests on IE?

Comment: No, this is the first issue I encountered. I'm just using the required `org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter` and this is the first IE related issue I can think of. I guess I'll have to go deeper while debugging..

Comment: Okay, I found out the attributes were null because the context is destroyed in IE, but not in the other browsers. I changed the question to match the problem now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue occured because the `<a:commandButton>` was placed in a nested form. By removing the form and the commandButton **outside** of the form it was originally in, the behavior is as expected.

It seems that IE is stricter on W3C norm concerning forms than Chrome & Firefox: [W3C Forms Norms](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/forms.html)

> Every form must be enclosed within a FORM element. There can be several forms in a single document, but the FORM element can't be nested.